# How to correctly read from multiple Kafka topics in a single Storm topology

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I have a Storm topology that must read from multiple Kafka topics and stream their output to a single bolt.

Currently I am using this code and it appears to be working fine:-

```java
final TopologyBuilder topologyBuilder = new TopologyBuilder();
topologyBuilder.setSpout(SPOUT_ID_1, new KafkaSpout(kafkaSpoutConfig1), 1);
topologyBuilder.setSpout(SPOUT_ID_2, new KafkaSpout(kafkaSpoutConfig2), 1);
topologyBuilder.setBolt(BOLT_ID, new SingleBolt(), 1).shuffleGrouping(SPOUT_ID_1).shuffleGrouping(SPOUT_2);
```

Is this the correct approach? calling `shuffleGrouping()` multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can calling `***Grouping()` multiple times.